# AspxGridView Truncate Text with "Show More / Less" Buttons

Tags: c#, devexpress, aspxgridview, devexpress-gridcontrol

There is an HTML UL list in my `aspxgridview` column. This column Encodes HTML and show the full list properly.

But some grid rows can be very wide to show. So I would like to truncate the texts in some columns and users can view all text with "show more" button?

How can I manage it on a `aspxGridView` cell ?

Comment: Hi! This question is perhaps too broad. Is there any more detail you can give? Have you tried to research this problem?

Comment: i search about 3 hours and found not the exact solution. we can truncate text with code offcourse. but how can i show "show more" button and run javascript in gridcolumn , this is the question.